# Null pointer exception in enhanced for loop over Vector

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, foreach

How could this code throw a null pointer exception?

```
for (Foo f : Vector<Foo> v)
{
    f.doStuff(); // this line throws a NullPointerException
}
```

Even if the Vector is empty, shouldn't the inside block just never be executed?

Comment: Is the Vector empty?  Did you run a debugger?  What are the contents of v?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Vector` is not empty.  As you say, if it was then the loop body would not be executed.

If you get an NPE on that line, it means that one (or more) of the elements of the `Vector` is `null`.

---

I should also point out that the example code is syntactically incorrect.  It should probably read something like this:

```
Vector<Foo> v = ...    
for (Foo f : v)
{
    f.doStuff(); // this line throws a NullPointerException
}
```

Comment: +1, @wohanley, If your data structure allows `null` values, then simply perform a "check" before you proceed to "do stuff" - `if(f != null){...}`. But this may be a non-issue for you.

Comment: You also get NPE if the Vector itself is null.

Comment: @user802421 Yes, but in a different line.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you show is incorrect, you can not declare both the step variable (Foo f) and the collection (Vector v) in the loop.  You will get a NullPointerException if the collection (v in your example) is null.  As noted above, you will also get a NullPointerException if the collection contains an element that is null.